# How do I change borderColor in native base Select Component?

Tags: css, react-native, native

I'm trying to change the `borderColor` on this Select Component from Native base.

Here is an image of the default color and the focused color:

[image]

The border is black by default. I already tried with `borderColor=""` and `none`/`unset` but it isn't changing the color.

How can I change the default and active border color?

The code is here..

````
 useState,
} from 'react';

import {
 Box,
 Select,
 CheckIcon,
} from 'native-base';

function Dropdown({
 options = [],
 placeholder,
 backgroundColor,
 className,
 onChange = () => {},
}) {
 const [value, setValue] = useState('');

 return (
   <Box>
     <Box width="3/4" maxWidth="300">
       <Select
         className={className}
         onChange={onChange}
         minWidth="200"
         selectedValue={value}
         accessibilityLabel="Choose Service"
         placeholder={placeholder}
         backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
         _selectedItem={{
           bg: 'teal.600',
           endIcon: <CheckIcon size="5" />,
         }}
         _focus={{
           bg: 'white',
         }}
         marginTop={1}
         onValueChange={(itemValue) => setValue(itemValue)}
       >
         {options.map((option) => (
           <Select.Item
             label={option.label}
             value={option.value}
             key={option.value}
             style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', padding: 5 }}
           />
         ))}
       </Select>
     </Box>
   </Box>

 );
}```
````

Comment: Please share the code snippet and also which library you are using for this?

Comment: Ya of course, im working with NATIVE BASE and the code is here..

Answer (score 5):

You can use `borderColor` to specify border color and `borderWidth` to specify border width. To specify border color for focused inside `_focus`.

```
const Example = () => {
  let [service, setService] = React.useState('');
  return (
    <Center>
      <Box w="3/4" maxW="300">
        <Select
          _focus={{ borderColor: 'yellow.500' }}
          borderColor="red.500"
          selectedValue={service}
          minWidth="200"
          accessibilityLabel="Choose Service"
          placeholder="Choose Service"
          _selectedItem={{
            bg: 'teal.600',
            endIcon: <CheckIcon size="5" />,
          }}
          mt={1}
          onValueChange={(itemValue) => setService(itemValue)}
        >
          <Select.Item label="UX Research" value="ux" />
          <Select.Item label="Web Development" value="web" />
          <Select.Item label="Cross Platform Development" value="cross" />
          <Select.Item label="UI Designing" value="ui" />
          <Select.Item label="Backend Development" value="backend" />
        </Select>
      </Box>
    </Center>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've figured out how to change the default border, but I stumbled upon this link to a possible regression thats now closed: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/4937

This solution helped me change the DEFAULT gray border color. Also helped with the border color of a button too:

`_light={{borderColor: 'amber.500'}}`